# In which directory are the templates related to woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I use the theme "bridge", and plugins: "visual composer" and "woocommerce".
I want to edit the "visual composer" elements related to woocommerce.
I'm looking for these files in a directory with a theme 
 /wp-content/themes/bridge/vc_templates,
and in the plugin directory 
 /wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/templates/shortcodes.
But I can not find files related to woocommerce (like 'add to cart', 'product', etc.)
in which directory are these files located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Woocommerce** templates are separate from **VC** templates

you can find **Woocommerce** templates in this directory:

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/
```

if you want to override these templates you can copy them in your themes folder like:

```
wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product.php
wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php
wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, these files are not associated with VC. I need to edit the components of VC.

Comment: If you browsed your theme directory, I'm sure you'll find woocommerce directory where you can override those templates

Comment: You're right. I did not look carefully, these are the standard shortcodes of woocommerce